# spring-boot 1.5.2+.RELEASE: Use more than one datasource with the same connection string

Tags: spring-boot, datasource, hikaricp

We have a spring boot application using hikariCP as connection pooler and multiple datasources to handle long jobs processing (basically it uses the same connection string with longer timeouts and a reduced number of connections)

Since 1.5.2.RELEASE upgrade, only the first datasource annotated with @Primary has its housekeeping and pool threads starting. The secondary one is simply discarded, although the debug shows the datasource initialization being executed.

With 1.5.1.RELEASE this worked properly, both group of threads would start.

Here are our datasources definitions

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@Profile("hikari")
@Validated
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Component
class HikariDataSourceConfig
{
  private final DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

  protected Properties setDataSourceProperties()
  {
    final Properties dataSourceProperties = new Properties();
    dataSourceProperties.put("driverType", "thin");
    dataSourceProperties.put("user", this.dataSourceConfig.getUsername());
    dataSourceProperties.put("password", this.dataSourceConfig.getPassword());
    dataSourceProperties.put("serverName", this.dataSourceConfig.getServer());
    dataSourceProperties.put("portNumber", String.valueOf(this.dataSourceConfig.getPort()));
    dataSourceProperties.put("databaseName", this.dataSourceConfig.getSid());
    return dataSourceProperties;
  }

  protected HikariDataSource initializeDataSource(final int maximumPoolSize)
  {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
    dataSource.setValidationTimeout(this.dataSourceConfig.getValidationTimeout() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setDataSourceClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
    dataSource.setConnectionTimeout(this.dataSourceConfig.getConnectionTimeout() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setMaxLifetime(this.dataSourceConfig.getMaxLifetime() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setIdleTimeout(this.dataSourceConfig.getIdleTimeout() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
  @Primary
  public DataSource dataSource()
  {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = initializeDataSource(this.dataSourceConfig.getMaximumPoolSize());
    dataSource.setPoolName(DataSourceConfig.CONNECTION_POOL_DEFAULT_NAME);
    dataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(this.dataSourceConfig.getLeakDetectionThreshold() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setDataSourceProperties(setDataSourceProperties());
    return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean(name = DataSourceConfig.DATASOURCE_ALT_NAME, destroyMethod = "close")
  public DataSource slowDataSource()
  {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = initializeDataSource(this.dataSourceConfig.getWorkingQueueSize());
    dataSource.setMinimumIdle(1);
    dataSource.setPoolName(DataSourceConfig.CONNECTION_POOL_ALT_NAME);
    dataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(this.dataSourceConfig.getSlowJobLeakDetectionThreshold() * 1000L);
    dataSource.setDataSourceProperties(setDataSourceProperties());
    return dataSource;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to configure spring to allow cloned datasources again?

Versions used:

- HikariCP: 2.6.1
- Spring-boot: 1.5.3.RELEASE
- Java: 1.8.121

-- **Edit**

It fails for both 1.5.2.RELEASE and 1.5.3.RELEASE

-- **Edit 2**

I tried to bind the second datasource to a different database, but the same issue occurs, the secondary datasource pool does not start.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is concretely. You're not using any of the auto-configuration so changing the spring boot version shouldn't matter.

Comment: I had an existing behavior with 1.5.1 for which I could only start one secondary connection pool  (if I had more than one non-primary bean, only the first one in the class definition would start).

From 1.5.2 onward, this is no longer the case, only one pool will start.